# render error ract-native (text strings must be rendered within a<text>component)

Tags: react-native

**I couldn't figure it out, I tried a lot of things**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJz6n.png)

```
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <view>
      <text>Hello</text>
    </view>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: my code is below

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, please [edit] your question to include your code as [formatted text.](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `<view>` and `<text>` instead of `<View>` and `<Text>`
try this,

```js
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default App;
```